# Duplicate the Nth line from a file using Unix command

Tags: linux, unix, gitlab-ci, pipeline

A sample of /etc/resolv config file is given below. How do I duplicate the second line (nameserver) by using the UNIX command?

My input file contains

```
search cyberciti.biz
nameserver 202.54.1.10
```

If I want to input file like this

```
search cyberciti.biz
nameserver 202.54.1.10
nameserver 202.54.1.10
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about your specific requirements I can't say for sure whether this will fit your needs, but the following perl one-liner will duplicate **all** lines beginning with 'nameserver'. Remove the '-i.bak' if you don't want a backup file created.

```perl
perl -i.bak -pe 'print if /^nameserver/' resolv.conf
```

This one will instead duplicate the second line of the file, regardless of its contents:

```perl
perl -i.bak -pe 'print if $. == 2' resolv.conf
```